# Using 2 peices of Java source code I get the error: Cannot find symbol when trying to compile

Tags: java, compiler-errors

I have researched many similar questions to my problem here, but none have been able to help.

I have 2 pieces of source code: **Proj02.java** and **Proj02Runner.java**. **Proj02Runner.java**. compiles successfully, but compiling **Proj02.java** produces this error:

```
Proj02.java:11: error: cannot find symbol
    System.out.println(Proj02Runner.run(randomNumber));
                       ^
  symbol:   variable Proj02Runner
  location: class Proj02
1 error
```

I realize that the error is occuring becasue **Proj02.java** cannot find **Proj02Runner.java**. I just cannot figure out how to fix it.

When the program runs using both sources, the output should be this:

```
128
Hello my name is xxx.

128
129
```

I expect the numbers to change each time the program is run, but the second number should always be one more than the first. Please note my assignment is that we are not allowed to change any code in **Proj02.java**. We must accomplish the task while only modifying **Proj02Runner.java**.

Here is my code:

**Proj02.java** code

```
import java.util.Random;
import java.util.Date;
import java.lang.Math;

class Proj02{
  public static void main(String[] args){
    Random generator = new Random(new Date().getTime());
    int rand = generator.nextInt();
    int randomNumber = Math.abs((byte)rand);
    System.out.println(randomNumber);
    System.out.println(Proj02Runner.run(randomNumber));
  }
}
```

**Proj02Runner.java** code

```
class Proj02Runner{
  static int run(int valIn){
    System.out.println(
      "Hello my name is xxx.\n");
    byte myVar = (byte) valIn;
    System.out.println(myVar);
    myVar = --myVar;
    return myVar;
  }
}
```

Any insight would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: how are you attempting to compile/run these files?  Are you manually running javac against the files, or is this within a IDE or build tool?

Comment: I am running them manually with a cmd using javac. Thanks.

Comment: Show us the exact command(s) you're using.

Comment: You'll need to compile both of them simultaneously, or add Proj02Runner to the classpath of javac when you attempt to compile Proj02.  The easiest way is to compile them both simultaneously --  put them both in the same directory, and then compile *.java

Comment: Most people move to a build system (gradle, maven, ivy, etc) or IDE project if they're going to do anything more complicated than a single file

Comment: Thanks, Gus. So I would compile like this? javac *.java Proj02.java Proj02Runner?

Comment: Not exactly; I added an answer that walks through the steps, hopefully that'll clear up the confusion.

Answer (score 0):

To solve the issue of having the second number being higher than the first.
Simply change `myVar = --myVar;` to `myVar = ++myVar;`

The full code is as follows:
`

```
public class Proj02 {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Random generator = new Random(new Date().getTime());
        int rand = generator.nextInt();
        int randomNumber = Math.abs((byte)rand);
        System.out.println(randomNumber);
        System.out.println(Proj02Runner.run(randomNumber));
    }
}

class Proj02Runner{
    static int run(int valIn){
        System.out.println(
          "Hello my name is xxx.\n");
        byte myVar = (byte) valIn;
        System.out.println(myVar);
        myVar = ++myVar;
        return myVar;
    }
}
```

`

This produces the following example output:

```
67
Hello my name is xxx
67
68
```

I hope this helps with solving your problem :)

Comment: I think you're answering OP's next question :)  You could include a compilation command line (probably `javac *.java`) to complete your answer

Comment: Thanks! I compiled together and I thought it worked - I didn't get any errors. But when I ran it I got this error:

`Proj02.java:11: error: cannot find symbol`
    `System.out.println(Proj02Runner.run(randomNumber));`
                                 `^`
  `symbol:   variable Proj02Runner`
  `location: class Proj021 error`
`error: compilation failed`

Answer (score 0):

Ewan's answer describes how to change the code; Here's what you can do to compile & run your code from the command line.

First, put the two files together in the same directory:

```
C:\demo>dir
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is C8EE-A280

 Directory of C:\demo

06/10/2021  10:55 AM              .
06/10/2021  10:55 AM              ..
06/09/2021  04:02 PM               367 Proj02.java
06/09/2021  04:02 PM               215 Proj02Runner.java
               2 File(s)            582 bytes
```

Then run `javac *.java`

```
C:\demo>javac *.java

C:\demo>dir
 Volume in drive C is OS
 Volume Serial Number is C8EE-A280

 Directory of C:\demo

06/10/2021  10:55 AM              .
06/10/2021  10:55 AM              ..
06/10/2021  10:55 AM               630 Proj02.class
06/09/2021  04:02 PM               367 Proj02.java
06/10/2021  10:55 AM               468 Proj02Runner.class
06/09/2021  04:02 PM               215 Proj02Runner.java
               4 File(s)          1,680 bytes
```

Now that it's compiled, you can run the code.  Java programs require a `public static void main(String[] args)` to be runnable, and that method is in `Proj02`, so that's the one you call out:

```
C:\demo>java -cp . Proj02
120
Hello my name is xxx.

120
119

C:\demo>
```

That should get you over the hump for this assignment.  I strongly recommend getting comfortable building with one of the build systems (gradle, maven, ivy, ant, etc) or at least an IDE project, because when you start doing more complex work you're going to want to include additional libraries, and the command-line method gets unmanageable quickly.